# Java Servlet HTTP Get Request to REST Server not working 404?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, apache-commons-httpclient

I have created a Java Servlet to act as a proxy for my Web page to make cross domain requests using AJAX to fetch XML's.

The servlet goes to a server using the parameters and returns back whatever it receives from that server where the XML is stored.

I am trying to figure out why my Java Servlet that is using a URL to fetch XML from a Web Logic Server that has REST is not working. However when I use the same URL and paste it into a browser (IE9, Firefox) I get an XML response back.

Here is my code:

```
// build URL for specific request
    String url = baseURL + urlParams;

    //debug - check constructed URL
    if (debug.equals("true"))
    System.out.println("Constructed URL is " + url);


    // fetch XML from URL
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getXML = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getXML);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

    // Echo whatever headers you are interested in.
    Header[] allHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();

    resp.setStatus(statusLine.getStatusCode());
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try
    {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(resp.getWriter());
        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content,"UTF-8"));
        String temp = null;

        while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //debug - check response body
            if (debug.equals("true"))
                System.out.println(temp);

            bufferedWriter.write(temp);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        resp.setStatus(500);
        // handle the exception
    }
    finally
    {
        if(bufferedWriter != null)
        {
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

**Servlet Details**
Using apache.http.client

Web XML 2.3

Web Server is Sun One 6.1 SP4 (yes I know this is legacy system)

As I said before, I checked my server log to see what URL the servlet was using and then I copied it to my browser and indeed there is an XML at that location.

Is the method I am using not the correct for REST?

Am I doing something wrong?

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you provide the exception you are getting and Stack Trace ?

Comment: I dont get an exception, I just get a 404 response to the servlet and the servlet outputs the 404 response to the logs

Comment: What kind of servlet container are you using?

Comment: Sun One 6.1 Web Server , using Web XML 2.3

Comment: My Java servlet is a proxy for web page to make AJAX calls to a remote server. The servlet should fetch the XML and then send it as a response back to the web page.

Comment: 404 comes, when path is not found.. are you sure about the URL formed ?

Comment: Have you checked what goes over the line via WireShark? I guess that the URL that's logged is actually not the one that is used.

Comment: My servlet is on a Solaris web server, I am going to check the access logs of the REST server